# ¿Qué hacer si el intento no es reconocido en Rasa NLU?

Tags: python, rasa-core, rasa-nlu

Al tener problemas con el tutorial, seguí el chatbot rasa de clima proporcionado por[Justina Petraityte](https://vimeo.com/254777331), puedes encontrar el repositorio de GitHub [aquí](https://github.com/JustinaPetr/Weatherbot_Tutorial). Sin embargo, mi chatbot nunca reconoce la intención que traté de darle cuando cuando intento con `run_online.py`, que tiene que ser la ubicación, y no sé cómo manejar este caso en la medida en que crea un error al llamar a la API meteorológica, que por lo tanto está vacía. Aqui esta `run_online.py` :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging

from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.channels.console import ConsoleInputChannel
from rasa_core.interpreter import RegexInterpreter
from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy
from rasa_core.policies.memoization import MemoizationPolicy
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def run_weather_online(input_channel, interpreter,
                          domain_file="weather_domain.yml",
                          training_data_file='data/stories.md'):
    agent = Agent(domain_file,
                  policies=[MemoizationPolicy(), KerasPolicy()],
                  interpreter=interpreter)

    agent.train_online(training_data_file,
                       input_channel=input_channel,
                       max_history=2,
                       batch_size=50,
                       epochs=200,
                       max_training_samples=300)

    return agent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level="INFO")
    nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('./models/nlu/default/weathernlu/test')
    run_weather_online(ConsoleInputChannel(), nlu_interpreter)
```

Por ejemplo, traté de preguntar por el clima en Italia pero, como pueden ver [aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jubgb.png). No reconoce a Italia como una intención, incluso si estaba en `data.json`.

Por lo tanto, ¿qué hacer cuando el intento no es reconocido? ¿Deberíamos aún guardarlo en stories.md?

**Contenido del archivo de domain** :

```
action_factory: null
action_names:
- utter_greet
- utter_goodbye
- utter_ask_location
- action_weather
actions:
- utter_greet
- utter_goodbye
- utter_ask_location
- actions.ActionWeather
config:
  store_entities_as_slots: true
entities:
- location
intents:
- greet
- goodbye
- inform
slots:
  location:
    initial_value: null
    type: rasa_core.slots.TextSlot
templates:
  utter_ask_location:
  - text: In what location?
  utter_goodbye:
  - text: Talk to you later.
  - text: Bye bye :(
  utter_greet:
  - text: Hello! How can I help?
topics: []
```

---

**Rasa Core version**:

```
(MoodbotEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot4$ pip list :
...
rasa-core (0.9.0a3)
rasa-nlu (0.12.3)
```

**Python version**:

```
(MoodbotEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot4$ python -V 
Python 3.5.2
```

**Operating system** : Linux 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastante extraño, pero después de volver a instalar el servidor, spacy, parece que resolvió el problema:

```
pip install rasa_nlu [spacy]
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
python -m spacy link en_core_web_md en
```

Supongamos que me olvido de descargarlo: /